# Is there a tech meaning behind the io extension for domains?

Tags: domains

I didn't see this asked on the site but from my research I know that .io originally belonged to the British Indian Ocean Territory which would go to the United Kingdom but I've noticed more tech blogs using the extension `io` in their domain. Is there any tech meaning behind `io` besides the meaning through British Indian Ocean Territory?

Comment: IO has been used for years to mean Input/Output in the tech world.

Comment: Not "originally". It still is a ccTLD, belonging to a country. People can attach different semantics to it, but those are just illusion. Same for `WS`, `TV` or `LA` that are countries but sometimes used or marketed with different meanings ("website", "television", or "los angeles").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Trebor mentioned, IO often means Input/Output in tech.

More details [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.io):

> In computer science, "IO" or "I/O" (pronounced I O) is commonly used as an abbreviation for input/output, which makes the .io domain desirable for services that want to be associated with technology. .io domains are often used for open source projects, application programming interfaces ("APIs"), startup companies, video games, and other online services.

Interestingly, the domain extension is used so frequently to mean "input/output" instead of "Indian Ocean" that Google sees the extension as generic/worldwide instead of using it to geotarget:

> Google's ad targeting treats .io as a generic top-level domain (gTLD) because "users and webmasters frequently see [the domain] more generic than country-targeted."